# Delete text from Canvas, after some time (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, text, time

I need to remove text from canvas after some time.

```
y = cnv3.create_text(600, 430, text='Authentication failed', font=('Times', 30), fill='yellow')
```

I tried this:

```
time.sleep(2)
cnv3.pack_forget(y)
```

Result: It does not even appear the text.

And this:

```
root.after(2000, cnv3.delete(y))
```

Not working too.

Please help, I looked almost everywhere and I didn't find how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give `after` a reference to a function. The way you're doing it is immediately calling the delete function and then passing the result of that to `after`.

It needs to look like this:

```
root.after(2000, cnv3.delete, y)
```